# ConstraintLayouts not working in landscape mode

Tags: android, xml

ConstraintLayout not working in landscape mode, please help.

**XML**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.375" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.625" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.750" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.875" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgHeader"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@drawable/paperranger" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDonate"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_button_payment_square"
        android:text="@string/donate"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline5"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCardNumber"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp8"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp8"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp8"
        android:text="@string/card_number"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/edtCardNumber"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline" />

    <com.omise.mobile.omisetumboon.ui.view.CreditCardEditText
        android:id="@+id/edtCardNumber"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp8"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp8"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp8"
        android:ems="10"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvCardNumber" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtCardName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp8"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp8"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp8"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp8"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp8"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp8"
        android:text="@string/name_on_card"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/edtCardName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline2"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="366dp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvExpairyDate"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp8"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp8"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp8"
        android:text="@string/expairy_date"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/spnYear"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline6"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCvv"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp8"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp8"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp8"
        android:text="@string/cvv"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/edtSecurityCode"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline6"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline3" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtSecurityCode"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp8"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp8"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp8"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberPassword"
        android:maxLength="3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline6"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvCvv" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp8"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp8"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp8"
        android:text="@string/amount"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/edtAmount"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline4" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtAmount"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp8"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp8"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp8"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="457dp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spnMonth"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp8"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp8"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp8"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/spnYear"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvExpairyDate" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spnYear"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp8"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp8"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dp8"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline6"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/spnMonth"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvExpairyDate" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Landscape**

[image]

**Portait**

[image]

Comment: if remove `tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp"` then ?

Comment: your image labels  are wrong may be portrait and landscape should be interchange...!!!

Answer (score 0):

tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp"

is fixing the height to absolute 25